# prove that a Paraboloid is a hausdorff measurable subset

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure, measurable-sets

I'm trying to study for my exam and the question is:

Let

$A=\{ ( x,y,z) R^3 : || (x,y )|| , z=1/2 ||( x,y )||^2\}$

Show that $A$ is a $H^2$ - measurable subset and calculate the surface area.

I don't have a problem computing the surface area but I don't know how to show the first part.

I would be really thankful if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: Hi Ismaat. What does "$H^2$-measurable" mean, in your view? Can you think of any set that is $H^2$-measurable?

Comment: So my problem is that i can't put 1 and 1 together. On the one hand we have a sentence which says: is U open and  phi injektiv and diffrentiable, then every lebesgue measurable subset E  from U is a H^n measurable subset.